# Rotating graphics?

Tags: c#

I have this code, that draws an image.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var tempRocket = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.rocket);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(tempRocket))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(tempRocket, 150, 150);
    }
}
```

Yet what do I do to rotate it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap b, float angle)
{
  //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
  Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height);
  //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
  using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap)) 
  {
      //move rotation point to center of image
      g.TranslateTransform((float)b.Width / 2, (float)b.Height / 2);
      //rotate
      g.RotateTransform(angle);
      //move image back
      g.TranslateTransform(-(float)b.Width / 2, -(float)b.Height / 2);
      //draw passed in image onto graphics object
      g.DrawImage(b, new Point(0, 0)); 
  }
  return returnBitmap;
}
```

Comment: The creation of the `Graphics g` should be baked into a `using` statement.

Comment: One additional thing I found, after returnBitmap is created:
            returnBitmap.SetResolution(b.HorizontalResolution, b.VerticalResolution);

Comment: Doesn't work as i expected. After rotate 30 degree - X and Y axis rotated too. I need draw to new position with unrotated axis ! Something like: g.DrawImage(b, new Point( UnrotatedNewX, UnrotatedNewY ) );
Translation after rotate will do on rotated axis (under 30 degre angle).

Answer (score 11):

There are overloads of `Graphics.DrawImage` that take an array of three points used to define a parallelogram for the destination, such as:

> ### [Graphics.DrawImage Method (Image, Point[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f9s3at1.aspx)
>
> #### Remarks
>
> The destPoints parameter specifies
>   three points of a parallelogram. The
>   three Point structures represent the
>   upper-left, upper-right, and
>   lower-left corners of the
>   parallelogram. The fourth point is
>   extrapolated from the first three to
>   form a parallelogram.
>
> The image represented by the image
>   parameter is scaled and sheared to fit
>   the shape of the parallelogram
>   specified by the destPoints
>   parameters.

There is also an article on MSDN describing the use of this method: [How to: Rotate, Reflect, and Skew Images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b575a03.aspx), with the following code example.  Unfortunately, the example complicates the issue by also skewing the image.

```
Point[] destinationPoints = {
          new Point(200, 20),   // destination for upper-left point of original
          new Point(110, 100),  // destination for upper-right point of original
          new Point(250, 30)};  // destination for lower-left point of original

Image image = new Bitmap("Stripes.bmp");

// Draw the image unaltered with its upper-left corner at (0, 0).
e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);

// Draw the image mapped to the parallelogram.
e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, destinationPoints);
```

---

The main differences compared to using the `Graphics.Transform` property are:

- This method does not allow you to specify the rotation angle in degrees -- you have to use some simple trigonometry to derive the points.
- This transformation applies only to the specific image.

  - Good if you only need to draw one rotated image and everything else is non-rotated since you don't have to reset `Graphics.Transform` afterward.
  - Bad if you want to rotate several things together (i.e., rotate the "camera").

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Graphics.RotateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform.aspx) to rotate the image.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var tempRocket = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.rocket);

    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(30.0F); 

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(tempRocket, 150, 150);
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't look right - you should apply the transform before drawing the rocket. And why are you creating `g` but not using it?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - regarding the `g`, quite right. This was taken from the OP post and I have now removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Version without clipping:

```
private Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float angle)
    {
        int w, h, x, y;
        var dW = (double)bitmap.Width;
        var dH = (double)bitmap.Height;

        double degrees = Math.Abs(angle);
        if (degrees <= 90)
        {
            double radians = 0.0174532925 * degrees;
            double dSin = Math.Sin(radians);
            double dCos = Math.Cos(radians);
            w = (int)(dH * dSin + dW * dCos);
            h = (int)(dW * dSin + dH * dCos);
            x = (w - bitmap.Width) / 2;
            y = (h - bitmap.Height) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            degrees -= 90;
            double radians = 0.0174532925 * degrees;
            double dSin = Math.Sin(radians);
            double dCos = Math.Cos(radians);
            w = (int)(dW * dSin + dH * dCos);
            h = (int)(dH * dSin + dW * dCos);
            x = (w - bitmap.Width) / 2;
            y = (h - bitmap.Height) / 2;
        }

        var rotateAtX = bitmap.Width / 2f;
        var rotateAtY = bitmap.Height / 2f;

        var bmpRet = new Bitmap(w, h);
        bmpRet.SetResolution(bitmap.HorizontalResolution, bitmap.VerticalResolution);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpRet))
        {
            graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            graphics.TranslateTransform(rotateAtX + x, rotateAtY + y);
            graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
            graphics.TranslateTransform(-rotateAtX - x, -rotateAtY - y);
            graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new PointF(0 + x, 0 + y));
        }
        return bmpRet;
    }
```

[Primary source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c7196c3-952a-417b-8ad3-45d47c1c3e73/c-rotation-image-problem)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply transformation matrix. 
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/matrix_transformation.aspx) you can find good example about transformations in GDI+