# Rotating picture in C# cuts the picture

Tags: c#, .net, image

I am trying to rotate a picture with C#, and am using this code:

```
///create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(newBMP.Width, newBMP.Height);
//make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
//move rotation point to center of image
g.TranslateTransform((float)newBMP.Width / 2, (float)newBMP.Height / 2);
//rotate
g.RotateTransform(-90);
//move image back
g.TranslateTransform(-(float)newBMP.Width / 2, -(float)newBMP.Height / 2);
//draw passed in image onto graphics object
g.DrawImage(newBMP, new Point(0, 0));
```

The `newBMP` is a bitmap that I getting from a form, and I am changing its size. Then I want to rotate it, but when I try this code above, it cuts the top and the floor of the picture.
After all of this, I save the new pic on the server.

All works fine except the rotate...

Anyone see the problem?

**solved** i used this: [C# rotate bitmap 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225363/c-sharp-rotate-bitmap-90-degrees)

Comment: Surely the width and height or the `returnBitmap` need to be swapped if you are rotating by 90°?

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. You can just change width and height for 90°, 180°. For any degrees see my solution here: [stackoverflow.com: C#, rotating Graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172906/c-rotating-graphics/48725273#48725273)

Answer (score 1):

If the bitmap is wider than it is tall, you're going to get cropping when you rotate it 90 degrees. You need to take that into account when you call `g.TranslateTranform`.

Comment: so i didnt understand what i should change...

Answer (score 0):

This answer was just answered (for any angle) for vb.net on stack overflow...

[How to rotate JPEG using Graphics.RotateTransform without clipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277221/how-to-rotate-jpeg-using-graphics-rotatetransform-without-clipping/23277295#23277295)

Should be easy to convert to C#

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap image, float angle)
    {
        //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image

        double radius = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(image.Width, 2) + Math.Pow(image.Height, 2));

        Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap((int)radius, (int)radius);

        //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
        using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap))
        {
            //move rotation point to center of image
            graphic.TranslateTransform((float)radius / 2, (float)radius / 2);
            //rotate
            graphic.RotateTransform(angle);
            //move image back
            graphic.TranslateTransform(-(float)image.Width / 2, -(float)image.Height / 2);
            //draw passed in image onto graphics object
            graphic.DrawImage(image, new Point(0, 0));
        }
        return returnBitmap;
    }
```